# title() method on string with non-valid ASCII

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters

I have a list of surnames and it isn't formatted the right way. Every name is written in cAmEl sTyLe -.-
I'm trying to make it look more clean with title() method.

```
s = 'KroGer'
s = s.title()
print s
>Kroger
```

This one works fine. But when I have non-ascii letter in the name:

```
s = 'KRöGer'
s = s.title()
print s
>KröGer
```

the letter that follows this non-ascii remains in Upper-case. Even if I change the string:

```
s = 'KRöger'
s = s.title()
print s
>KröGer
```

I still get the wrong result. 
Why does it behave this way? How can I make this string become 'Kröger'?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally found a way to do what I want. God bless generators:

```
name = 'KRöGer'
name = ' '.join(name[0].upper() + name[1:].lower() for n in name.split())
print name
>>Kröger
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be a [unicode string](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type):

```
>>> 'KRöger'.title()
'KröGer'
>>> u'KRöGer'.title()
u'Kröger'
```

**Edit:** A simple python script as an example:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
print 'KRöger'.title()  # 'KröGer'
print u'KRöGer'.title()  # 'Kröger'
print 'KRöger'.decode('utf-8').title()  # 'Kröger'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I get UnicodeEncodeError when trying to follow your example. 
Furthermore, I have a list with thousands of strings. Do I have to check somehow if the string is a unicode string?

Comment: Try adding `# -- coding: utf-8 --` at the very beginning of your file (the one that contains those strings).

Comment: Yeah, i have this line as a first line of my code...
Btw I use python 2.7 if this could help somehow...

Comment: I edited my post with a simple scripts that runs perfectly well on my computer in Python 2.7.5. Try running it and if it runs ok, try identifying and describing additional relevant bits of complexity that your program contains that are not present in this simple test program.

Comment: It's very strange. I've made a black .py file and copy-pasted there your 4 lines of code. And I get "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6'" on the second print statement.
Update: checked on my mac os machine and ubuntu linux - result is the same...

Answer (score 1):

You could decode UTF 8 before the title:

```
print s.decode('utf-8').title()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Trying to run your example I get:'ascii' codec can't encode character...